# Conditional Array initialization

Tags: rust

Can I conditionally provide an initialization for a vector or no initialization at all?

```
fn main() {
    let b = true;
    let a = vec![
        if b {"b"} //error[E0317]: `if` may be missing an `else` clause
    ];
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vec!` macro doesn't support this, but you can use normal functions on [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```
fn main() {
    let b = true;
    let mut a = Vec::new();
    if b {
        a.push("b");
    }
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c4206e6a24cd20e2bf31922a26af461)

Comment: Alternatively, just have to different vecs: `if b { vec!["b"] } else { vec![] }`

Comment: If you want to protect immutability in a better way @Masklinn's alternative solution can be much more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```rust
let my_vec = if condition {
   vec!["b"]
}
else{
   vec![]
};
```

Another option is late initialization:

```rust
let my_vec: Vec<&str>;

if condition{
   my_vec = vec![];
}
else{
   my_vec = vec!["b"];
}
```